# Google AdMob Interstital Ad causing memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, admob

Using MAT and a hprof dump file, I found there are two instances of main activity in my application when I rotate the screen. Note package names have been redacted :)

[image]

This is the incoming objects of MainActivity$1

[image]

Class References of MainActivity$1

[image]

When I show the path of GC roots excluding weak references on the InterstitialAd class I get the following output.

[image]

My understanding in terms of domination or roots is that the reference interstitialAd which is my object is preventing this garbage collection. Im not sure what ky or IQ is though.

This is my interstitial Ad implementation. Please note that my app only has a single activity.
I will show parts that relate to the InterstitialAd only to be clear and concise.
**Main Activity**

```
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() 
            {
                if(isTheAppInFrontOfTheUser)
                {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() 
            {
                interstitialAd = null;
                SharedPreferences userPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPrefs.edit();
                editor.putLong("dateTimeOfLastInterstitialAd", System.currentTimeMillis());
                editor.commit();


            }
        });
}
```

This is what is called to request interstitialAd

```
public void showInterstitialAd()
    {

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build(); 
            interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);


    }
```

My On Destroy method

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
        interstitialAd = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Please help, im not sure what is wrong with my interstitial ad implementation which causes it to leak!

Answer (score 0):

I'm only seeing a single instance of MainActivity in your log. `0x41c7af8`. Where is the other one?

NB the ACRA ErrorReporter holds a WeakReference to lastActivityCreated.